# Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.0 Submenu Looks Messy on Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.x and already able to use multilevel submenu as I apply here:
[Simple Multilevel Menu With Bootstrap 2.1.x](http://doxadigital.com/scrape/multilevelmenu.php).

But the problem arise when its collapse. **The default view is expand all**. This doesn't look good as the menu will cover the whole screen on iPhone.

I would like to know: is there any function to collapse all when the collapse menu button triggered? (The sub-menu should be open when user clicks it.)

Please let me know your thought about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to add some responsive styles.

```
@media (max-width: 979px){
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This ensures that your submenus are hidden on collaps mode.
If you hover (or click in Bootstrap 2.1) over them they will be shown via the basic bootstrap dropdown-menu styles and js.

Here you can find a [Demo - jsfiddle (BT 2.0.2)](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/SmKAB/2/)

Comment: Hi... your demo works.. i try to add the css in my html, why it doesn't work ? any idea.. please check http://doxadigital.com/scrape/multilevelmenu.php ... also in mobile/tablet there probably no hover event, does the click event replaced the hover event in your solution ?

Comment: I guess your new styles get overwritten by the ```css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css```. Try to include the ```@media (max-width: 979px)``` part after your ```css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css``` include.